# Angular2 Linking between service and model

Tags: angular

I've been working with Angular 2 for a bit, but have found myself an issue I've not found a clear solution to, namely how to create a link between a service and a model. While components can inject a service and cause this to stay singleton, making it available globally, I have models I wish to declare within these components. Trying to pass a service like this will seemingly cause it to create a "snapshot" of the current class state, and will not update when I apply changes to my service.

Allow me to give an example of what I mean. Take the following "LanguageObject" model: It's a model that stores several strings for different languages, which should return the correct string based on the currently defined language in a language service:

```
export class LanguageObject {
  nl : string;
  fr : string;
  en : string;

setvalues(nl : string, fr: string, en: string) {
    this.nl = nl;
    this.fr = fr;
    this.en = en;
  }

  selectedlanguage : string;

  constructor(private languageService : LanguageService) {
    this.selectedlanguage = languageService.language;
  }

  get() :string{
    if (this.selectedlanguage == "nl") {
      return this.nl;
    } else if (this.selectedlanguage == "fr") {
      return this.fr;
    } else {
      return this.en;
    }
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {


  language : string;

  constructor() {
    this.language = "en";
  }
}
```

But the models themselves are called like this, losing the proper link to the service:

```
constructor(private languageService : LanguageService) {
    this.continuestring = new LanguageObject(languageService);
    this.continuestring.setvalues("Verder","Continuer","Continue");
  }
```

Consecutively, changing the value of the language in the service will not cause my models to update unless I reload the value into them, while I would like for them to do this automatically.

Which leads to my question, **how would one properly achieve the desired effect of allowing these models to retrieve the service value? Do we use a form of injection, or does angular2 provide a better method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I'm missing something in your question, but if you want to `LanguageObject.selectedlanguage` always be equal to `LanguageService.language`, you don't need `selectedlanguage` at all... Especially since you store reference to `LanguageService` as private property of `LanguageObject`. I.e.

```
export class LanguageObject {
    get() :string{
        if (this.languageService.language == "nl") {
            return this.nl;
        } else if (this.languageService.language == "fr") {
            return this.fr;
        } else {
            return this.en;
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, I would consider changing design so `LanguageService` will return language value, instead of `LanguageObject`.